# Is it possible to estimate the abundance of conformers from J values?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, nmr-spectroscopy, free-energy, conformers

I have a system of two disubstituted cyclohexanes and I want to estimate the abundance/ratio of the two based on the J values and if possible, roughly estimate the difference in free energy.

[image]

To get the extreme values of the J constants I have been provided with the data from the system on the image below.

[image]

This is all the information I have been provided with.
Is it possible to approximate the ratio and free energy difference and if so, how?

Comment: I suspect there might be something wrong with the problem, since the averaged values should be bracketed by the extrema. However there is only one extremum larger than the average values. It should be possible to bracket each of the averages by separate pairs of extrema.

Comment: Karplus curves should come in handy.